# Better way to view TFS changesets? VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015, team-explorer

Our dev team is currently implementing TFS / Team Explorer 2015 for tracking code changes.  Powerful tool, but we find the method of viewing Changeset Details within a work item to be unnecessarily complex.  Unless we're missing something, the only way to do this is to double click on a change set in the "All Links" or "Version Control" menus, which then launches the details in another pane.

We would like a simple grid showing changeset details (`ID`, `Comment`, `Associated Project`, `File Name`, etc) visible in the main console, i.e. in the "Version Control" pane.  (If there are multiple files associated, it should display a unique line for each.)

Is that possible?  If not, does anyone know of any add-in tools that would provide this functionality?  Or any other method we might accomplish this?

Comment: Currently, you have to follow the method you described to view the linked changesets in a work item. If you would like to show the changeset details in the opened work item, you need to customize the Work Item template via adding a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a custom report. The information you're looking for isn't really something that lends itself to being displayed in a flat grid. A changeset can (and will) consist of changes to multiple files, for example.

I believe there's an in-the-box report that shows this information but I can't confirm that at the moment. If not, it should be easy to create -- the information  you're looking for is definitely in the data warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to show changeset details in work item, you need to work with custom work item control to get the changesets information programmatically.

1). To the work item's associated changesets, you can use the following code (quoted from this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2006/08/12/getting-changeset-objects-from-associated-work-items/))

```
WorkItem workItem = wiStore.GetWorkItem(workItemId);
        List<Changeset> associatedChangesets = new List<Changeset>();
        foreach (Link link in workItem.Links)
        {
            ExternalLink extLink = link as ExternalLink;
            if (extLink != null)
            {
                ArtifactId artifact = LinkingUtilities.DecodeUri(extLink.LinkedArtifactUri);
                if (String.Equals(artifact.ArtifactType, “Changeset”, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    // Convert the artifact URI to Changeset object.
                    associatedChangesets.Add(vcs.ArtifactProvider.GetChangeset(new Uri(extLink.LinkedArtifactUri);
                }
            }
        }
```

2). For detailed information on how to create custom work item control, see: https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/